# How to redirect multiple URL to one folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect multiple url to the one folder. I have tried to use htaccess file ,but it doesn't work.
I have following base url `http://super.com/smth/dst`

Directory structure is the same

```
-smth
--dst
--...
--whatever
```

I need to redirect multiple URLs to the same folder, `dst` in my case.

Examples of urls that should be redirected to this folder.

`http://super.com/smth/dst/level0`
`http://super.com/smth/dst/level1`
`http://super.com/smth/dst/level2`
`http://super.com/smth/dst/levelx`

Is it possible to get something like that

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources out there that explain everything about .htaccess redirection, so here's only the short answer to your question.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^smth/dst/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)?$ /smth/dst [NC,L]
```

or, if you also need the foldernames that are cut, and the query-string:

```
RewriteRule ^smth/dst/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)?$ /smth/dst?request=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

note, that now everything after `smth/dst/` will be passed into `$_GET['request']`

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by these way, try following code :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^smth/dst/(.*)$ smth/dst/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^smth/dst/(.*)/$ smth/dst/index.php [QSA,L]
```

It may help you.

Comment: If you dont want to redirect to index.php page then just remove it.